# Algorithm Negotiation failed when trying to connect to server

Tags: 16.04, ssh, openssh

I installed `openssh-server` in `Ubuntu server 16.04` and in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` I added:

```
MaxAuthTries 3
PasswordAuthentication YES
```

and then restarted the ssh server. When I try to connect from a a different pc with ssh I get a message
`Algorithm Negotiation failed`

back in server, when I run `systemctl status ssh` I get this error

`Unable to negotiate with 192.168.0.132 port 63428: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1`

I edit the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` add I add the line

```
KexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

and now I get a different error, when I run the `systemctl status ssh`

`Unable to negotiate with 192.168.0.132 port 63428: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc, blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,twofish-cbc,arcfour [preauth]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are connecting to new system (Ubuntu 16.04) from some very old SSH client that does not support any contemporary algorithms and this is a reason why it fails to connect. You should really update your client.

Or continue enabling the outdated protocols that might not be secure today. Using

```
KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
Ciphers +aes128-cbc
```

you should be able to connect.

Comment: I  used `open ssh` client to login to my server. I didn't realize that the client was the problem. I downloaded putty, delete the entries I added and I login successfully. Thanks for the info!

Comment: The client is not a problem. The "old client" is a problem. You can download up-to date OpenSSH too.

Answer (score 1):

Add below code into file: `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
Ciphers +aes128-cbc
```

Now restart Service